# LRT tests and sufficiency

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

If $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$, let $\lambda$ be an LRT statistic for $\mathbf{X}$ and $\lambda^*$ and LRT statistic for $T$. Is it true that $\lambda=\lambda^*$?

According to theorem 8.2.4 of the book "Statistical Inference" by Casella and Berger, seems to be the case, but the proof relies on an artifact of the factorization theorem that I think is only true with discrete distributions. The proof is as follows
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\lambda(\mathbf{x})&:=\frac{\sup_{\Theta_0}L_{\mathbf{x}}(\theta)}{\sup_{\Theta}L_{\mathbf{x}}(\theta)}=\frac{\sup_{\Theta_0}f_{\theta}(\mathbf{x})}{\sup_{\Theta}f_{\theta}(\mathbf{x})}\\&=\frac{\sup_{\Theta_0}g_{\theta}(T(\mathbf{x}))h(\mathbf{x})}{\sup_{\Theta}g_{\theta}(T(\mathbf{x}))h(\mathbf{x})}=\frac{\sup_{\Theta_0}g_{\theta}(T(\mathbf{x}))}{\sup_{\Theta}g_{\theta}(T(\mathbf{x}))}=\lambda^*(T(\mathbf{x}))\text{, }
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
according to the book, the last equality is true as long as $g_{\theta}$ is the density function of $T$, but I think this only holds if the population is discrete (watch [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4020927/doubt-about-neyman-pearson-lemma-and-sufficiency-fisher-neyman-factorization)).

Answer (score 0):

The test you showed is the Generalized one...but just to understand the problem take as an example the more suitable Neyman Pearson Lemma for simple hypothesis.

You have that the test is

$$\frac{L(\theta_0|\mathbf{x})}{L(\theta_1|\mathbf{x})}\leq k$$

now observe that "IF" a sufficient estimator $t(\mathbf{x})$ esists NP lemma becomes

$$\frac{h(\mathbf{x})\cdot g(t(\mathbf{x}),\theta_0)}{h(\mathbf{x})\cdot g(t(\mathbf{x}),\theta_1)}\leq k$$

$$\frac{ g(t(\mathbf{x}),\theta_0)}{ g(t(\mathbf{x}),\theta_1)}\leq k$$

thus the rejection region depends  by the data ONLY through a Statistic, that is $t(\mathbf{x})$, sufficient for the model.

Example 1:

$X\sim Exp(\theta)$

You perform the test using $T=\Sigma_iX_i$, sufficient statistic (in this case, Minimal, Sufficient and Complete) and you can use chi-squared tables,

Example 2

$X\sim N(\mu;1)$

you perform your test again using $T=\Sigma_iX_i$ or, what is the same, the sample mean...again $T$ is CSS (complete and sufficient)

Example 3

$X\sim U(0;\theta)$

and you perform your test basing it on $T=X_{(n)}$, the maximum of your observations, Complete and sufficient statistics

---

Other UMP test generalizing NP Lemma or Generalized LR Test (which is not anymore UMP) work in the same way: if a Sufficient estimator exists, the test is based on this important estimator... and it is very intuitive because the Sufficient estimator is so named as it include all the information you need to estimate the parameter...

Comment: Yes, I get that $\lambda(x)=\mu(T(x))$, but I don't know how this implies that $\lambda(x)=\lambda^*(T(x))$, neither in the NP lemma case nor in the generalized LRT case. I mean, the quotient of $g$'s need not be the quotient of likehoods of $t$'s, or, at least I don't see why.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Tenorio : I think that the explanation I gave you is very intuitive. If a numerical example can persuade you I will give you one. If not, please advise because I have no time to waste.

Comment: My question was essentially the following: Can the function $g$ in my question (and in your answer) always be chosen to be the density function of $t$? If not, the proof in my question (and in the book) is wrong, and is only valid for the discrete case. Then, is there another proof?